# Unable To Cast object type 'System.String[*]' to type 'System.String[]'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, casting, opc

Hi everyone i had a issue with a code in C# .NET, I'm using a DLL for connect to OPC Servers the DLL that was used in a VB.NET project and works with no problem at all.

I'm trying to show a list of available Servers in a ListBox, the code used in VB.NET (and works) is this one:

```
Dim AllOPCServers As Object
AllOPCServers = AnOPCServer.GetOPCServers

' Load the list returned into the List box for user selection
Dim i As Short
For i = LBound(AllOPCServers) To UBound(AllOPCServers)
    AvailableOPCServerList.Items.Add(AllOPCServers(i))
Next i
```

and i wrote this to use in the C# application

```
try
{
    var _listOPCServer = _OPCServer.GetOPCServers();
    foreach(var i in _listOPCServer)
    {
        string serverName = (string)i;
        listServers.Items.Add(serverName);
    }             
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    lstMsg.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + " Error al Obtener Lista de OPC's: " + exc.Message);
}
```

On Debug mode on Local tab shows this:

_listOPCServer | {string[1..2]} | dynamic {string[]} |

```
[1]        |  "Server01"    | string  
[2]        |  "Server02"    | string
```

**UPDATE:**

I get the error in line "foreach(var i in **_listOPCServer**)"

**Unable To Cast object type 'System.String[*]' to type 'System.String[]'**

That is the actually error.

I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong, can someone help me?

Comment: Here is a minimal reproduction for a *similar* case: `(string[])(new string[0,0])`, although I do not know how to produce that exact message .. in any case, please post the *real error message* (copy and paste) to avoid possible errors.

Comment: On which line do you get the error?  I don;t see where you're trying to cast `_listOPCServer` to anything.

Comment: @pst that is the error that i get Unable To Cast object type 'System.Sting[*]' to type 'System.String[]'

Comment: @DStanley i get the error in the line foreach(var i in _listOPCServer)

Comment: @DStanley haha sorry, bad spelling, is String, let me correct that

Answer (score 5):

Ok i found a way to work this out and it's only a mod of your advices

```
 Array _listOPCServer = (Array)(object)_OPCServer.GetOPCServers();               

            foreach(object i in _listOPCServer)
            {
                string serverName = (string)i;
                listServers.Items.Add(serverName);
            }
```

I only added (object) in the declaration and works fine, now i can show the list of servers just the way i wanted it

or also do this

```
Array _listOPCServer = (Array)(object)_OPCServer.GetOPCServers();               

            foreach(object i in _listOPCServer)
            {
                listServers.Items.Add(i);
            }
```

Again, thanks a lot for your help and time!

Answer (score 2):

VB.NET is a lot more astute at dealing with non-conforming array types.  Don't hesitate to use it, .NET make it easy to have languages inter-operate with each other.

At issue is that OPC is a COM based standard.  The server you are using is returning a SAFEARRAY with a non-conforming lower bound, the first index is 1.  Not 0.  Not that unusual in COM, choosing between 0 and 1 as the first array index is like the endian problem or arguing whether a tomato is a fruit or a vegetable (It is a fruit.  And little-endian is the right kind of vegetable).

However, 0 as the lower bound is what C# insists on when dealing with one-dimensional arrays.  It wants a "vector", a distinct array type that always has one dimension with a lower bound of 0.  Heavily optimized in the .NET runtime.  What you get back doesn't match so is mapped to a *multi-dimensional* array with *one* dimension.  Not an array type you can express in the C# language.

You *can* hack it in C#, but you'll have to use the Array type explicitly.  Something like this, spelled out for clarity:

```
Array servers = (Array)_OPCServer.GetOPCServers();
int first = servers.GetLowerBound(0);
int last = servers.GetUpperBound(0);
for (int ix = first; ix <= last; ++ix) {
    var elem = (string)servers.GetValue(ix);
    // etc..
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `foreach` still work on a non-zero-based array?  Where does the cast come in to play?

Comment: No idea actually.  It never occurred to me to try it, the illusion that an array implements `IEnumerable<T>` is bound to fall down on this kind of code.  Just try it.  The cast is obvious, Array.GetValue() returns an Object.

Comment: I meant the cast from `System.Sting[*]` to `System.String[]` that the OP is getting the exception for.

Comment: Well, no, that cannot possible work.  The tenure of my answer.  A vector is not compatible with an multi-dimensional array with one dimension.

Comment: I understand that; what I don't understand is _why_ the compiler is trying to cast to a `string[]`.  I've added an answer with my guess.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant thanks for the time for answer my question, but after post the question here i found an explication about that you're commented here, i tried also declaring as Array type but i get the same error on the line Array servers= (Array)_OPCServer.GetOPCServer

Comment: Like @ManuelEspino says, the error still pops on the server variable creation. Casting to object before casting to array makes it work like in ManuelEspino describes in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

While Hans is correct in distinguishing the difference between a zero-based array and a non-zero-based array, I still don't see why you're getting that exception.

My guess is that you're declaring `_OPCServer` as `dynamic`, which defers type-binding until run-time.  Thus `_listOPCServer` is `dynamic` as well.

Since you're iterating over the array and extracting `string`s, the compiler *may* be trying to cast the object to a `string[]` which as Hans points out is invalid.

You should be able to cast `_listOPCServer` to an `Array` and use the `foreach` just as you are:

```
Array _listOPCServer = (Array)(_OPCServer.GetOPCServers());
foreach(var i in _listOPCServer)
{
    // etc.
```

Comment: Hi thanks for taking a time for answer this, but i tried as well the way that you recommended but still get the same error in the line Array _listOPCServer = (Array)(_OPCServer.GetOPCServers());

Comment: I get the same error I'll update the post with some screenshots